# How to change one color from bitmap to another color

Tags: android, kotlin, image-processing, imageview, imagefilter

I have an image and I need to change some colors to another
for example, I need to change all red colors to green (all in range {#00ff0000 -> #ffff0000} to  {#0000ff00 -> #ff00ff00})

I tried ColorMatrix but did not work:

```
    var mat: Array<Float> = arrayOf(
         255f, 0f, 0f, 0f, (-128*255).toFloat(),
            0f, 255f, 0f, 0f, (-128*255).toFloat(),
            0f, 0f, 255f, 0f, (-128*255).toFloat(),
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
            0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f
    )
    cm.postConcat(ColorMatrix(mat.toFloatArray()))
    // then setColorFilter
```

Advice!

Comment: Would just changing the hue also work? Can you give an example input and output image?

Comment: The color format you are using is ARGB, yes? Also, in what format is the image (`Bitmap`?)